# How to focus trap with styled-components? How to access classname from styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, focus, accessibility, styled-components

I'm currently using `styled-components` 5.0.1 with React. https://styled-components.com/

For context, my goal is to focus trap within a modal.

My problem is that classnames are randomly generated from `styled-components` so I'm not able to access these DOM nodes with `querySelector`. My other problem is that I'm not able to use React ref forwarding since I would have to do a lot of ref forwarding between component trees.

Is there a way to access the classname that is generated from styled-components? If so, I can use `querySelector` and go about the usual way of focus trapping by accessing the DOM nodes through `querySelector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by accessing the DOM nodes with using a `data-` attribute.

For example,

```
const myComponent = styled.div`
  // ...styles here
`;

const foo = () => (
  <myComponent
    data-foo-bar="foobar"
  />
);

console.log(document.querySelector('[data-a11y-id="HeaderNavBar-SearchButton"]');
// returns the DOM element for myComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your component should be able to process the passed-in css:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
    
    const Box = styled.div`
      color: red;
      ${props => props.addCSS}
    `;
    
    const DatePicker = () => <Box>DatePicker</Box>;
```

Secondly, declare the css style.

```
import { css } from "styled-components";

const myCSS = css`
  font-size: 60px;
`;
```

Lastly, pass it down to the child component.

```
<DatePicker addCSS={myCSS} />
```